# How to Get current Zone using NodaTime.Tzdb

Tags: c#, timezone, nodatime

Using c#
and using NodaTime.Tzdb
My target is to get the zone Id for my current timezone.

As per https://nodatime.org/TimeZones
my current zone Id should be  Europe/Copenhagen

But I am not sure how to get.
DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();

but it is giving me "Europe/Paris"

Anyone know how to get the current TimeZone using NodaTime tzdb

Comment: For fun, I tried it too and got Europe/Berlin even though I'm in Stockholm Sweden.

Comment: sir @jonskeet could answer this :)

Comment: The current timezone is set by your OS and picked up by the .net startup code.

Comment: @gilliduck `Europe/Stockholm` is an alias of `Europe/Berlin` -- What do you get with `BclDateTimeZone.ForSystemDefault();`?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're using Windows, and that `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` will return "Romance Standard Time".

Noda Time uses the [CLDR](https://cldr.unicode.org/) data to convert between Windows time zone IDs and TZDB IDs. That data maps a single Windows ID to multiple TZDB IDs, and the "primary" mapping to use has `territory` value of "001".

If you look at the [CLDR v41 data line 341](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/main/data/cldr/windowsZones-41.xml#L341) you'll see this (with the following lines included for reference):

```xml
<mapZone other="Romance Standard Time" territory="001" type="Europe/Paris"/>
<mapZone other="Romance Standard Time" territory="BE" type="Europe/Brussels"/>
<mapZone other="Romance Standard Time" territory="DK" type="Europe/Copenhagen"/>
<mapZone other="Romance Standard Time" territory="ES" type="Europe/Madrid Africa/Ceuta"/>
<mapZone other="Romance Standard Time" territory="FR" type="Europe/Paris"/>
```

In other words, Europe/Paris is the primary mapping, and Europe/Copehagen is another mapping for the same Windows zone ID. There's no way for Noda Time to differentiate between them.

Europe/Copenhagen is actually a link in TZDB to Europe/Berlin (which interestingly has a different Windows ID: "W. Europe Standard Time").

The good news is that from 1977 in Europe/Paris and from 1980 in Europe/Berlin, those zones have followed the "EU" - so as long as you're dealing with dates and times after 1980, it shouldn't (currently, at least) matter whether you use Europe/Paris or Europe/Copenhagen.